# Schema.getGlobalDescribe() get ObjectType Describe

Tags: sobject, describesobject, dynamic-apex

I'm trying to get the `DescribeSObjectResult` by writing the following code:

```
public String fObjectName {get;set;}

fObjectName = (String)Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('objname');
DescribeSObjectResult objSchema = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(fObjectName).sObjectType.getDescribe();
```

Getting error:

> Expression of type Schema.SObjectType has no member named sObjectType

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global describe call returns a Map of Strings to `sObjectType`

```
Map<String,SObjectType>();
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm

Simply use

```
Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(fObjectName).getDescribe();
```

The Error

> Expression of type Schema.SObjectType has no member named sObjectType

Also explains that the `Schema.SObjectType` is the working value and has no member of SObjectType because it is already that

You should probably cache the results of the global describe as well if you plan on using the results again as it is a fairly expensive call.

Comment: +1 although as a Reminder; you can't cache DescribeSObjectResult or DescribeFieldResult classes. The global describe itself can be cached, though.

Comment: @Eric: if I tried the following `DescribeSObjectResult objSchema = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(fObjectName).getDescribe();` I get the following error : `System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object` but I debug the `fObjectName` and I'm getting the value which is `employee__c` but if I hardcode like this `DescribeSObjectResult objSchema = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('employee__c').getDescribe();` then its working, why is it not taking `fObjectName` ?

Comment: @NickKahn - Its not case sensitive so either your debug is in the wrong place and it is null when you use it in the above or it is not actually `employee__c` like you think. Are you sure its 2 __ and not one? There is nothing special about the property that is different than a hardcoded string unless they are not the same

Comment: its odd that when hard-coded its working and if it passing as a string param then complaining about de-reference a null and also i found the similar issue if it passed as variable then its returning null, please see https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009AsUIAU

Comment: maybe its casting issue? I tried cast to `DescribeSObjectResult objSchema = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(string.valueOf(fObjectName)).getDescribe();`

Comment: @NickKahn - you are getting the NPE because it cannot find a value in the map for fObjectName. use this as a guide `System.debug(Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account').getDescribe());` as for why your param is not correct, it could be 100 reasons. you will have to post up your current code AND debug logs matching the code. You are looking at it wrong and as usual the SF developer forums are just confusing things for you